# $p$-value Definition

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I was reading **Statistical Inference** (2nd edition) by *George Casella* & *Roger L. Berger* when I came across a formal definition of p-value, followed by a theorem stating that

> Let W(X) be a test statistic such that large values of W give evidence
>   that $H_1$ is true. For each sample point x, define 
>   $$p(x)=\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} P_{\theta}(W(X) \geq W(x))$$ Then,
>   p(X) is a valid p-value.

My question is what if the test statistic is the one whose small values give evidence that $H_1$ is true? Is the $p$-value defined as $\inf_{\theta \in \Theta_0} P_{\theta}(W(X) \leq W(x))$ in that case?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: That's an awful definition. It seems to define "a valid p-value", so presumably that contrasts with an invalid p-value.

Comment: If by "small" you mean "very negative," then replace $W$ by $-W$ and apply the definition.  For other concepts of "small" it's likely a similar procedure will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you would still use the supremum, so in that case the p-value would be:

$$p(x)=\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} P_{\theta}(W(X) \leqslant W(x))$$

Comment: The intuition here is that we’re considering the worst case scenario: what’s the biggest our probability could be given any parameters? Then we know that the real probability of getting that small of a statistic is bounded above by that.